# Keyboard shortcut to switch black/white or foreground/background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was watching a video tutorial and the instructor seemed to switch the colour of a layer from white to black with a shortcut, since his cursor did not leave the layer thumbnail section, per below...

[image]

Does anyone know which shortcut that would be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Option/Alt-Delete = Fill with foreground color
- Command/Ctrl-Delete = Fill with background color
- Command/Ctrl-i = Invert

Chances are the instructor was using one of these shortcuts.

Comment: Another one could have been `Shift-x` to switch foreground color and background color around. Very usefull in masks

Comment: You don't need shift. `X` will toggle the foreground/background color, but that doesn't change the actual image. The shortcuts I provided alter the image itself, this is why I didn't mention the `X` shortcut. `Shift-X` applies a gradient to a shape layer, since the OP mentions flat colors I didn't think `Shift-X` was appropriate.

Comment: Yes, `X` alone works. But I thought it could have been used in combination with "Fill with foreground/background color". I thought it useful extra information. I could have guessed you already evaluated including this shortcut and decided against it. Shift-X does not behave as you describe it in my photoshop cs6 (default shortcuts). There actually does not seem to be a `Shift-X` shortcut by default.

Comment: In Photoshop CC `Shift-X` fills vector layers with the default gradient (and toggles colors). This may be a bug, but that's how it behaves here. And your'e correct `Shift-X` does nothing in Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Also very useful: if you add the Shift key to the Fill shortcuts mentioned above, only the non-transparent pixels are filled with the respective foreground/background color.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can toggle your background and foreground color with <kbd>D</kbd> and then use the fill shortcuts [given above](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-black-white-or-foreground-background/20650#20650).

Comment: On Mac + Photoshop CS6, the keyboard shortcut to toggle between foreground and background color is "`X`"

Comment: `D` sets foreground and background colour to black and white respectively, but does not switch.

Answer (score -1):

Command Shift 5 then to go back command shift 2 - to check values - this is what you mean - OBVIOUSLY not invert colours....

Comment: Command-Shift-5 has no function. If you mean Command-5, all that does is switch to the Blue channel in an RGB document or Yellow channel in a CMYK file. Then Command-2 (not command-shift-2) will switch back to the composite channel. Nothing you've posted actually **does** anything to the file. It merely changes what you *see* but does not alter any pixels whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Hit "D" for background color and "X" for foreground color.

Comment: This is wrong: D reverts to black foreground / white background and X swaps background and foreground colours. Neither of them would change the colour of the layer.